# When do we say "Drink to your success"?

Tags: idioms

Do we say "drink to your success"

1. BEFORE the success (We wish somebody success); or
2. AFTER the success (We congratulate somebody on their success)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this answer is late, but it's both. It's more common to say it before though.

Often the "drink" part is omitted. So someone would raise a drink and simply say "to your success".

I think that the other answer actually misinterprets that dictionary entry. **"Let's drink to your success in your new job."** refers to wishing someone well for the future.

Comment: I agree with you that “success in your new job” is a hope for future success, but it is also a celebration of someone having already secured a new job. So, I think like most things in English, it’s complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible!

[The “drink to” entry in the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English says](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/drink-to) -

> *to wish someone success, good luck, good health etc before having an alcoholic drink*:[British English] ***"Let's drink to your success in your new job."***

So, it is used **after** the task as it is celebrating the success.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the dictionary lists various uses of 'drink' and they all are interesting! OP's question is typically taken as an example on Longman.

Comment: so what do we say BEFORE the success?

Comment: @haile All the best; Best of Luck; My wishes are with you... and many more personal messages!